# launching a method after a certain time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i'm trying to lunch a method from alarm manager in the same class. Well, in  my service class i have this method:

```
new loadSomeStuff().execute();
```

How can i launch it after 3 hours using alarm manager?

```
public class MyIntentService extends Service {
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    public static String prefName = "SecretFile";
    public static String version = "56";
    public final static int uniqueID = 1394885;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //i want after the alarm manager stop to launch this method.
        new loadSomeStuff().execute();
    }
```

Comment: @user2607848 I have reverted your changes to the question. Please start a new question if you have more problems rather than completely change your original question. Otherwise, the answer by CommonsWare makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Step #1: Create a `PendingIntent` that will launch your service

Step #2: Get an `AlarmManager` by calling `getSystemService()` on some `Context`, such as your activity

Step #3: Call `set()` on `AlarmManager` to schedule your `PendingIntent` to run in three hours

However:

- Please consider using an `IntentService` if possible, rather than a `Service` with what would appear to be an `AsyncTask`
- If you are anticipating this work to be done even if the device is in sleep mode in three hours, you will need to use a `_WAKEUP`-style alarm and something to keep the device awake while the work is going on, such as [`WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) or [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful)

Comment: why should i use IntentService instead of Service?

Comment: @AndroidArabia: So that the service goes away as soon as it is done, rather than continuing to take up memory.